# How to create a transparent layer in windows phone?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to create a transparent layer in Windows Phone? What I need is? In the first screen there are two buttons and in the second screen, a transparent layer should be formed when a button is pressed and a ListPicker over the transparent screen. When a value is selected in the ListPicker, the value should be binded with the button's content name which is in the background screen. And this transparent screen and ListPicker should get disappeared.Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: You can use `Opacity` property of UI elements to deal with transparencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a canvas, choose its fill color, size etc, and set the opacity to the right value to give your effect

Or create a semi-translucent .png image and set that as a source of an image in your project.

For a smooth transition use a storyboard to fade in the image or canvas.